# NoReverseMatch with 2 slug parameters in django

Tags: django

i have the following problem.

I want to have a detailview on this url: `127.0.0.1:8000/<category-name>/<product-name>` (`category-name` and `product-name` is slug field.) right from the index page. Please help :(

My error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /products/ Reverse for 'ProductDetail' with arguments '('new-things', 'flower-pot')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['products\\/\\<slug\\:category\\.slug\\>\\/\\<slug\\:product\\.slug\\>$']
```

my (relevant part) index.html:

```
{% for p in Product %}
  <a href="{% url 'product:ProductDetail' p.category.slug p.slug %}">{{ p.name}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

my (relevant part) urls.py:

```
from .models import *

app_name = 'product'
urlpatterns = [
    path('product/<slug:category.slug>/<slug:product.slug>', views.ProductDetailView.as_view(), name="ProductDetail"),
]
```

and (relevant part) my models.py:

```
    class Product(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        description = models.TextField()
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)

            def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
                if not self.id:
                    # Newly created object, so set slug
                    self.slug = slugify(self.name)

                super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

            def __str__(self):
                return self.name


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if not self.id:
                # Newly created object, so set slug
                self.slug = slugify(self.name)

            super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

Comment: in url template tag `p.category.slug` is not right. as `product` doesn't have `category` field.

Comment: You can return multiple list by using `zip` function in your views.  `m_list = zip(list(Category.object.all()), list(Product.object.all()))` and then in template iterate it like this`{% for c, p in m_list %}`.

Comment: hello sorry, i updated my models.py, somehow i deleted it by editing the question

Comment: so there is no "easy" way to pass 2 slug parameters in an url call?

Comment: Of course there is.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to use dots in the parameter names. Use underscores:

```
path('product/<slug:category_slug>/<slug:product_slug>', views.ProductDetailView.as_view(), name="ProductDetail"),
```

However, this still won't really work as you are trying to refer to a category via a product; but your models don't have any relationship between Product and Category. I assume you need to have a ForeignKey from Product to Category.

Comment: i have edited it, i have a foreignkey to category (by editing the question it got deleted)
thanks that actually helped, but now i am getting another error 

AttributeError at /products/new-things/flower-pot
Generic detail view ProductDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug.

Comment: Well then you need to show ProductDetailView, but this is probably a separate question (and you should accept the answer to this one).

Answer (score 0):

First, `Product` model does not have `category`. Append `ForeignKey` to your `Product` model.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE) # change on_delete what you want.

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if not self.id:
                # Newly created object, so set slug
                self.slug = slugify(self.name)

            super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

Second. Your url settings is wrong. You can not use `.` in url param. Change your code.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('product/<slug:category_slug>/<slug:product_slug>', views.ProductDetailView.as_view(), name="ProductDetail"),
]
```